# Create file with 751 permissions at creation

Tags: linux, permissions, vi

I keep creating practice perl scripts in a linux directory using `vi <filename>` and need to `chmod 751 <filename>` before I can run it as I wish to. I'm sure there is a simple way to default my permissions or config them at creation, but I'm not familiar with it - ayuda me por favor.

Comment: Why don't you write a script to create a new one with the correct permissions? `#!/bash/bin touch $1; chmod 751 $1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to make a bash alias for `vi` which will first create the file and then change it's permissions before opening it. Use something easy to remember, like `vix` (x for executable bit):

e.g. (untested):

```
function vix {
        touch $1
        chmod 751 $1
        vi $1
}
```

Note that aliasing vi itself is a bad idea as many other programs call on it directly, which may cause issues with your system.

Comment: Re "aliasing vi itself is a bad idea as many other programs call on it directly": They would be unaffected by aliases or shell functions. (`system()` uses `sh -c` which ignores all rc files, and `exec*()` skip the shell entirely.) ...edit: apparently, exporting a shell function _does_ affect `sh -c`.

Comment: Depends on how the script/program is invoking it, but generally correct.

Comment: all solid points -- now I know I'm not not missing a hidden ability of `vi` itself. I use both root & user dev on this system - which files do I need to edit to cover both?

Answer (score 1):

751 doesn't make much sense for scripts - it allows "others" to execute the file, but not read it. (For scripts, which don't get *setuid* honored, this is impossible.)

To set default permissions for newly created files, you can use either *umask* (per-process) or *default ACLs* (per-directory). But they both can only *remove* permission bits; neither of them will *add* the "executable" bit automatically unless the program specifically asks for it. (For example, `fopen()` always requests 0666, the sane default for files.)

You will have to follow mjb's suggestion of writing a script that creates a file and immediately updates its permissions. Alternatively, run your practice scripts like `perl foo.pl`, which does not require the executable bit.

Comment: good points - just so you know, I don't want coworkers who I may share the code w/being able to read the content of the file, but I don't mind if they run it. Hint that 1 at the end.

Comment: @mjb: As I said in the *first paragraph* of my answer, I'm not sure how that could possibly work.